# CEF crashes when calling AfxFreelibrary

Tags: c++, dll, crash, chromium-embedded

I create a MFC DLL, which implement CEF initialize, shutdown and another functions. When I use this DLL, `CefInitialize` and other function all normal, but my program crashes in `AfxFreeLibrary`. At this time, CEF Shutdown has excuted success and no error occured.

This is my CefSetting:

```
CefSettings cefSettings;
CefSettingsTraits::init(&cefSettings);
cefSettings.windowless_rendering_enabled = TRUE;
cefSettings.multi_threaded_message_loop = TRUE;
cefSettings.no_sandbox = TRUE;
cefSettings.single_process = false;
```

This is the call stack:

[image: Call stack]

it looks like the thread wait a event timeout and touch off NOTREACHED();

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information it is difficult to give advice. Please make sure that your application structure is correct. You may want to consult the section  ["Application Structure"](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-application-structure) of the documentation. Your process is started multiple times so you must make sure the other processes can start-up correctly.

Depending on the application structure it can be feasible to work with a "Separate Sub-Process Executable". I think it is generally a good a approach to work with a separate sub-process executable as it simplifies a lot.

Btw. you can easily test if the application structure is a problem by running with

```
cefSettings.single_process = false;
```

If everything works fine in this case I would start to investigate on how your application is being executed in multi-process configuration.